# Class="dropdown" and attribute data-dropdown-menu not working with nested ul

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm tying to get a ul to drop down a few link icons, but no matter what I type, the only thing that changes is the orientation of the icons. I feel like I'm missing something rather simple, but nor Google or Foundation's website have helped. I've tried calling to the nested ul using .menu li a i {}, but that's wrong. I've tried other ways as well with no positive results.

```css
/* Styles go here */

.menu-hover-lines {
  margin-top: 30px;
  float: right, bottom;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
}

.menu-hover-lines li a {
  padding: 0.75rem 0;
  color: #333;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-right: 4rem;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.menu-hover-lines li.active>a {
  background-color: transparent;
}


/* Nav transition settings */

.menu-hover-lines a::before,
.menu-hover-lines a::after {
  height: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  transition: all 0.40s ease;
  background-color: #932929;
  width: 0;
}

.menu-hover-lines a::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.menu-hover-lines a::after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.menu-hover-lines a:hover::before,
.menu-hover-lines .active a::before,
.menu-hover-lines a:hover::after,
.menu-hover-lines .active a::after {
  width: 100%;
}

.menu li a>i {
  display: none;
}

.menu i:hover {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.1/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<ul class="menu dropdown vertical menu-hover-lines" data-dropdown-menu="">

  <li>
    <a href="">Get in touch</a>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Email me!"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://twitter.com">
          <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tweet me!"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://instagram.com">
          <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Message me!"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add a div to the outside of all your content for the hover effect

```css
/* Styles go here */

.menu-hover-lines {
  margin-top: 30px;
  float: right, bottom;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
}

.menu-hover-lines li a {
  padding: 0.75rem 0;
  color: #333;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-right: 4rem;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.menu-hover-lines li.active>a {
  background-color: transparent;
}


/* Nav transition settings */

.menu-hover-lines a::before,
.menu-hover-lines a::after {
  height: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  transition: all 0.40s ease;
  background-color: #932929;
  width: 0;
}

.menu-hover-lines a::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.menu-hover-lines a::after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.menu-hover-lines a:hover::before,
.menu-hover-lines .active a::before,
.menu-hover-lines a:hover::after,
.menu-hover-lines .active a::after {
  width: 100%;
}

ul .menu {
  display: none;  
}

 .drop_down:hover  ul .menu{
  display: inline; 
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.1/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="drop_down">
<ul class="menu dropdown vertical menu-hover-lines" data-dropdown-menu="">

  <li>
    <a href="" class="hover_text">Get in touch</a>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="content">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Email me!"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="content">
        <a href="http://twitter.com">
          <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tweet me!"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="content">
        <a href="http://instagram.com">
          <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Message me!"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: that did the trick, thanks! But now I'm having problems with the other nav links activating the drop down menu. Any recommendations?

Comment: is it using the same classes as this icon nav?

Comment: Yes, should it not be?